# WORKDIR не создает директорию

Tags: docker

Подскажите почему в контейнере не создана директория?
Вот DockerFile

```
FROM node:16.13-alpine AS base

WORKDIR /usr/app/test/

RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

COPY ./test/ .

FROM nginx:1.20-alpine
LABEL version="1.0"

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY ./test/dist/my-app/ .
```

Создал образ, запустил, захожу в него, а там нет директории

```
/usr/app/test
```

При создании образа ошибок нет:

```
Step 1/9 : FROM node:16.13-alpine AS base
 ---> 710c8aa630d5
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR /usr/app/test/
 ---> Running in dbe3994e667a
Removing intermediate container dbe3994e667a
 ---> 54b36120290d
Step 3/9 : RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
 ---> Running in e301f90c084f
Removing intermediate container e301f90c084f
 ---> ca6dc8541ba5
Step 4/9 : COPY ./test/ .
 ---> e00bf919a630
```

Создаю образ:

```
docker build ./my-app/ --tag my-app:v1
```

контейнер

```
docker run --rm -ti -d --name my-app my-app:v1
```

захожу в него:

```
docker exec -ti my-app /bin/sh
```

Вот что в контейнере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё создаётся https://pastebin.com/rJRWSbn9. Показывайте как проверяли и остальные 5 шагов которые вы не показали

Comment: Вы точно зашли в первый контейнер, а не во второй? Покажите полный лог сборки и как именно вы «заходите» в контейнер

Comment: А разве это я не образ создаю - my-app:v1? А на его основе контейнер - my-app?

Comment: Вы создаёте два образа. И ставите тег на последний, т.е. на контейнер с nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте разные Dockerfile или [--stage](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specifying-target-build-stage---target) ключ при сборке.
По умолчанию собереться только последний образ. В вашем случае это nginx.